# Node and Express application sending POST request twice

Tags: json, node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

This is my route code.

```
router.post('/content', function(req, res) {
    var topic = req.body.inputText;
    console.log("topic :"+topic); //shows correctly
    var somedata = "";
    console.log("request arrived for URL", req.url); //prints "request arrived for URL /content" only once


    var url = '<the-url-from-which-i-fetch-json'+topic;
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var wikitext = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", JSON.stringify(wikitext[0]['content'])); //prints the content only once as needed
         res.render('newcontent', {
            text : JSON.stringify(wikitext[0]['content'])
         });
      } else {
        console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode);
      }
    });

});
```

This is an instance of json data fetched.

```
{"topicname":"wiki","content":"<p>A <strong>wiki</strong> ([audio=en-us-wiki.oggˈwɪki] [WIKee]) is a <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/website\">website</a> which allows <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/collaborative_software\">collaborative</a> modification of its content and structure directly from the <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/web_browser\">web browser</a>. In a typical wiki, text is written using a simplified <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/markup_language\">markup language</a> (known as \"wiki markup\"), and often edited with the help of a <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor\">rich-text editor</a>.(ref: Britannica)<a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopædia_Britannica\">Encyclopædia Britannica</a>volume=1publisher=<a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopædia_Britannica,_Inc.\">Encyclopædia Britannica, Inc.</a>year=2007location=Londonurl=http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/1192819/wikiaccessdate=April 10, 2008]</ref></p>\n<p>A wiki is run using <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki_software\">wiki software</a>, otherwise known as a wiki engine. There are dozens of different wiki engines in use, both standalone and part of other software, such as <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bug_tracking_system\">bug tracking system</a>s. Some wiki engines are <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/open_source\">open source</a>, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access); for example, editing rights may permit changing, adding or removing material. Others may permit access without enforcing access control. Other rules may also be imposed to organize content. A wiki engine is a type of <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/content_management_system\">content management system</a>, but it differs from most other such systems, including <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/blog_software\">blog software</a>, in that the content is created without any defined owner or leader, and wikis have little implicit structure, allowing structure to emerge according to the needs of the users.(ref: Easy Wiki Hosting )</p>\n<p>The encyclopedia project <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia\">Wikipedia</a> is by far the most popular wiki-based website, and is in fact one of the most widely viewed sites of any kind of the world, having been ranked in the top ten since 2007. Wikipedia is not a single wiki but rather a collection of hundreds of wikis, one for each language. There are at least tens of thousands of other wikis in use, both public and private, including wikis functioning as <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/knowledge_management\">knowledge management</a> resources, <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/notetaking_software\">notetaking</a> tools, <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_community\">community websites</a> and <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/intranet\">intranet</a>s.</p>\n<p><a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham\">Ward Cunningham</a>, the developer of the first wiki software, <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WikiWikiWeb\">WikiWikiWeb</a>, originally described it as \"the simplest online database that could possibly work\". \"<a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wikt:wiki#Hawaiian\">Wiki</a>\" (pronounced [ˈwiki][group=note/w/lang=haw] <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/phoneme\">phoneme</a> varies between [wlang=haw] and [vlang=haw], and the realization of the [/k/lang=haw] phoneme varies between [klang=haw] and [tlang=haw], among other realizations. Thus, the pronunciation of the Hawaiian word <em>wiki</em> varies between [wikilang=haw], [witilang=haw], [vikilang=haw], and [vitilang=haw]. See <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_phonology\">Hawaiian phonology</a> for more details.}}) is a <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language\">Hawaiian</a> word meaning \"quick\".</p>\n","date":"2016-03-16T03:23:11.735Z"}
```

This is `newcontent.jade`

```
#{text}
p HELLO SSUP
```

In the output, I get the data of `text` variable printed twice.I tried on both firefox and chrome, and same issue persists. (There is no `favicon` loading anywhere, as this was mentioned to be an issue in certain threads). So what can be wrong in this code?

[Output has the text printed twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAAAI.png)

`HELLO SSUP` is printed at the end, after both content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You do not need to additionally `stringify` the `wikitext[0]['content']` because its type is already a string:

```
console.log(typeof wikitext[0]['content'])
// string
```

2) You use escaping in the template: `#{text}`

So:

***router***:

```
res.render('newcontent', {
   text : wikitext[0]['content']
});
```

***template***:

```
!{text}
p HELLO SSUP
```

or

```
div!= text
p HELLO SSUP
```

Comment: How was escaping it printing twice?

Comment: Most likely this is a bug: template tries to wrap the contents of the output variable in the tag and cannot cope with this. Try `p #{text}` for example.